# Managing sessions in magento on k8

Tags: magento2

Our team building ecommerce in `remix.run` and deploy it on `kubernetes`. Our backend is also deployed on the k8 and it’s `magento 2` via `grapql` /using apollo-client/. But we're facing following problems.

1. When the guest/customer adds the product to his cart, another guest/customer's products are appears
2. When user logged, when the user tried to get the shopping cart information, magento gave an The current user cannot perform operations on cart 'XXXXX' error.

Our app working fine in the development env. I think it's session related issue. I also enabled `Session Affinity` in Kubernetes but no luck. I'm out of mind. Please help me

Comment: Can you share your ingress files